# How to match German Umlaut (uppercase Ü) in htaccess rewrite-rules?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a vanity-url redirect as a rewrite rule in `.htaccess`, including German Umlaut `ü` (Umlaut in the path, no Umlaut-Domain with those double-dashes...):

```
RewriteRule ^(uber|ueber|über|%C3%BCber|%C3%9Cber)([_-]mich)?\/?$ 
    https://somewhere-else.com [NC,R=301]
```

Remarkably, it works for: `mydomain.com/uber...`, `ueber-me`, also lowercase `mydomain.com/über` **does work**.

The only thing **not** working is übercase `mydomain.com/Über`. Though I did verify the correctness of my URI-encodings with [rishida](https://r12a.github.io/apps/conversion/)...  `%C3%BCber` `%C3%9Cber?` it should be.

Confusing…

Answer (score 0):

Aye, that was easy:

Any `ü` and `Ü` comes in unencoded (in my case, might differ between clients…), however: Option `NC` does not bother about case-neutral matching for non-standard characters, thus I have to explicitly match both variants, upper and lowercase `ü`:

```
RewriteRule ^(uber|ueber|über|Über| <-- NEW ...
```

(still leaving the encoded ones for Overzealousness. Not taking bets other clients won't URI-encode… :o)

Comment: You can use : `RewriteRule ^([uüÜ]ber|ueber)`. Which is sometimes easier to read in this kind of case

Answer (score 0):

For case-insensitive matching you can use `(?i)` as prefix.

```
RewriteRule (?i)^(uber|ueber|über|
```

Source: https://serverfault.com/a/499007/115370